# Converting camera frame to grayscale image and display

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Actually i'm new on opencv, i was trying to convert the frames captured from the camera to gray scale and diplay those grayscale frames.... hereis my code 
When compile my code it generates exception

> > First-chance exception at 0x75942EEC in FYP.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception     at memory location 0x00C0FAA0.
> >     If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

```
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\cxcore.h>
#include <opencv\ml.h>
#include <opencv\cvaux.h>
#include <opencv\cvwimage.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
Mat gray_serial(Mat img){
    int rows = img.rows;
    int cols = img.cols;
    Mat gray(rows, cols, CV_8UC1);
    for (int r = 0; r<rows; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c<cols; c++){
            Vec3b bgr = img.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
            double gray_val = 0.144*bgr.val[0] + 0.587*bgr.val[1] + 0.299*bgr.val[2];
            gray.at<unsigned char>(r, c) = (unsigned char)gray_val;
        }
    }
    return gray;
}
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    Mat color_img;
    CvCapture* cv_cap = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    cvNamedWindow("Video", 1); // create window
    for (;;) {
        color_img = cvQueryFrame(cv_cap); // get frame
        imshow("Video", color_img);
        //cvShowImage("Video", color_img); // show frame
        imshow("img", gray_serial(color_img));
        /*{
            int rows = color_img.rows;
            int cols = color_img.cols;
            Mat gray(rows, cols, CV_8UC1);
            for (int r = 0; r<rows; r++){
                for (int c = 0; c<cols; c++){
                    Vec3b bgr = img.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
                    double gray_val = 0.144*bgr.val[0] + 0.587*bgr.val[1] + 0.299*bgr.val[2];
                    gray.at<unsigned char>(r, c) = (unsigned char)gray_val;
                }
            }
        }*/
        c = cvWaitKey(10); // wait 10 ms or for key stroke

        if (c == 27)
            break; // if ESC, break and quit
    }
    /* clean up */
    cvReleaseCapture(&cv_cap);
    cvDestroyWindow("Video");
}
```

Comment: cv::Mat someMat(source);
cv::Mat grayMat;
cv::cvtColor(someMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this block:

```
            for (int r = 0; r<rows; r++){
                for (int c = 0; c<cols; c++){
                    Vec3b bgr = img.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
                    double gray_val = 0.144*bgr.val[0] + 0.587*bgr.val[1] + 0.299*bgr.val[2];
                    gray.at<unsigned char>(r, c) = (unsigned char)gray_val;
                }
```

by this one function

```
cvtColor(color_img,gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```